# Can not find module './contracts/PetShop.json' - Build artifacts are not sent to /src folder

Tags: reactjs, solidity, truffle

I am trying to write a simple UI client app which will read the smart contract to fetch some data. However I am stuck in getting the build artifact inside the /src folder. During deployment of the smart contract (migrate) on a local Truffle network, I noticed the build artifact is not getting copied over to src folder. However I have mentioned it in the truffle config file.

1. truffle config content

```
const path = require('path');
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname + 'client-app/src/contracts'),
```

2. App.js - I have already defined an import statement

```
import PetShop from './contracts/PetShop.json';
```

The react app was created using the npm module create-react-app.

But during the deploy, the contract artifact is not copied over to /src - hence it gives could not find module error.

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
PS C:\Users\HP\new-react> node src/dare.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './build/contracts/so.json'
Require stack:
   - C:\Users\HP\new-react\src\dare.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\new-react\src\dare.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\HP\\new-react\\src\\dare.js' ]
}
```

The answer to this is very simple, make sure you point your react file to the right path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu1wR.png)

Before I referenced the path correctly, it showed an error.

```
const MyContract = require('./build/contracts/so.json');
```

To correct the error do this:

```
const MyContract = require('../build/contracts/so.json');
```